# Django - pass data from basic HTML form into model

Tags: python, django, database, forms, model

I have created a simple app in Django using some tutorials, but it became very usefull and also scaled a lot.
What i have is a basic HTML table - prefilled with data from Model A.
At the end of the table there is Submit button, which just use some javascript to prompt a print window (to save the table[page] as PDF basically)

What i would like to do, is that when i press the Button to print, i would also pass some data from the table for example ModelA name and adress into a ModelB - which would serve as an statistic.

However i have used for this a simple tutorial, and therefore to display the table i used "DetailView" in views.py. This is my views.py file

```
class PrinterDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Printer
    template_name = 'printer_detail.html'
```

Is it possible to achieve this without redoing the whole site? i Found some people searching for simillar answers, but from that it seemed like i would have to redone whole app..

Thanks for your input!